# Problems amplifying mV potential differences

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, current-measurement, datalogger

I am trying to help my daughter with her science fair project of measuring efficiency of different types of household lighting in various heating conditions.  Since she doesn't have the electronics experience I volunteered to make the current data logger.

In order to measure the current going into the light I am using a poor mans toroidal coil (see picture).  I am getting a potential difference between the two ends of the coil of around 2-4 mv AC when a typical lamp is turned on.  I am trying to amplify this potential difference so I can feed around 2-5V analog DC into an Arduino for data logging.
[image]

So far I have tried just strait diode rectification (that didn't work as the input voltage to Ardunio isn't enough I suspect).  I then tried to use an 741 op-amp to amplify this potential, however that is also failing (see circuit below) as I get no output voltage (not sure why).
[image]

My question is: can anybody point me to a simple circuit to boost these potential difference in my coil to something I can rectify and log?  OR is there a simpler (non-expensive) way to accomplish current level datalogging?

EDIT:

I supplied +/- 5V to the 741, since that is the max V that the Aurdino can handle. The Toriodal coil was made from a piece of steel pipe 2" (3/4" dia.) long covered in electrical tape. It had 200 turns of 20 ga magnet wire. There is a slit down the side of the pipe. R1 was a 10 ohm resistor and R2 was a 1500 ohm resistor. I figured that should have given me several hundred millivolts AC, but I got no output at all on the 6 pin. If that had worked I was planning on going from a 10 ohm resistor for R1 to a 1 Ohm resistor. If there is a better op-amp to use I can switch out the 741 .

I attached one end of the coil to the 741 input (3 in the diagram) and the other I attached to the ground.

[image]

Edit:  figures for recommending Op Amp in comments.
[image]

Comment: 1 - Please give more details about your "poor man's toroidal coil". 2 - What supply voltages did you use for the 741? They don't work well with anything less than +/- 15. 3 - What resistors did you use? 4 - Since you are trying to make a current transformer, you need to load the secondary output.

Comment: I supplied +/- 5V to the 741, since that is the max V that the Aurdino can handle.  The Toriodal coil was made from a piece of steel pipe 2" (3/4" dia.) long covered in electrical tape.  It had 200 turns of 20 ga magnet wire.  There is a slit down the side of the pipe.  R1 was a 10 ohm resistor and R2 was a 1500 ohm resistor.  I figured that should have given me several hundred millivolts AC, but I got no output at all on the 6 pin.  If that had worked I was planning on going from a 10 ohm resistor for R1 to a 1 Ohm resistor.  If there is a better op-amp to use I can switch out the 741.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast what do you mean by the secondary output?

Comment: Any transformer (except, in a sense, an autotransformer) has a primary and a secondary winding. In your case the primary is the power cord, and the secondary is the multiple turns around the core. Please do some research on "current transformer". Try something like a TL081 for your op amp.

Comment: Thanks what properties of the TL081 lead you to recommend it?

Comment: The data sheet. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl081.pdf figures 5 and 6.

Comment: You don't need a non-inverting circuit since you will amplify AC. Use more like 10K and 1K or 100K and 10K. Or use R1 = 10K and for R2 use a 1M pot. The 10 ohm is too small. Does your meter have a serial interface? You can use the AC voltage setting to get a true RMS value of the op-amp output.

Comment: Please explain in more detail the current transformer you made - what is the slit for?

Comment: @Andyaka The slit is to get the wire through easier and so I can push the coil over the wire to the lamp without cutting it.  Since I was getting potential across the coil leads I did not think I needed to close it up.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer Sorry my meter does not have a serial interface.  I will try to use larger resistors and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your amplifier looks good in theory. Most likely the 741 and the low input signal is the culprit. The µA741 is a very old OpAmp. It was a good chip 40 years ago. These days you should only use them (if at all) for educational purposes. (They are really robust little chips that can take a lot of abuse, that's why they are popular in school and university).

Anyway, back on topic: I've designed something that may work for you:

[image]

U1 is your non inverting amplifier. I picked some reasonable resistors which give a gain of around 256.

U2 is a peak detector. The amplified positive half-cycles get rectified and charge capacitor C1 up to the maximum voltage seen at the non-inverting OpAmp input. After a few mains cycles you will see a constant voltage here.

Now you can sample this voltage from the Output pin. If you want to do a new measurement, just put a 0.1 second high pulse (3.3 or 5V) onto the reset input. This will let the transistor conduct and discharges the capacitor for the next measurement.

You need a bipolar power supply (not shown). +/- 5V is fine.

If you have to go shopping for a OpAmp, try to get a precision OpAmp which has enough output compliance. E.g. you'll want something that can drive the output  close to the positive supply as possible. The TL081 suggested by others will not do this. With a +/- 5V supply it will only go up to 2V. Ideally you'll want a rail-to-rail OpAmp, but you may get away with a cheap LM358 as well (goes up to 3.5V on a +/- 5V supply).

One last thing: You may want to put some more windings on your inductor. 2 to 4 mV is not much and close to the noise generated by the OpAmps themselves. A healthy input voltage would be in the range of 20 to 40 mV. Adjust the resistors around U1 accordingly.

Comment: Should there be a burden resistor on the coil itself, given that otherwise it's just connected to a very high impedance input?

Comment: @pjc50 Jup! There should be one. Forgot it.. I'll edit the post later.

Answer (score 0):

Using just a diode won't work because the voltage is too small to overcome the 0.7V turn on voltage of a silicon diode.  However you can combine the diode with the 741 op amp to make a precision diode which will operate at millivolt input levels because the turn on voltage of the diode is divided by the open loop gain of the op amp.  Just google "precision diode circuit" to find a variety of configurations that you can use.

Comment: Are you saying that the reason why my Non-Inverting amplifier failed is that the input voltage was only 3mV?

Comment: I don't know.  How did you connect your coil to the amplifier? Did you provide a DC path for the non-inverting input? In any case, the output would still be AC and would need to be rectified to produce a DC voltage. If you show the complete circuit, then it can be better critiqued.

Comment: I am not worried about rectification yet. that is easy to do at a later stage once the signal is boosted.  My question was around how to boost the potential differences I see in my coil to a usable level.  The circuit I tried to use amplification is shown in the question.